# Set notation question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a set S.

I want to talk about two further sets

S' = the set of functions from S into the powerset of the powerset of S.

S'' = the set of functions from S into S'

What's the standard notation for S and S''?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\mathcal P(X)$ for powerset and $X^Y$ for the set of functions from $Y$ to $X$, 
$$ S'=\mathcal P(\mathcal P(S))^S$$
and
$$S''=S'^S=\left(\mathcal P(\mathcal P(S))^S\right)^S\approx \mathcal P(\mathcal P(S))^{S\times S}.$$

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you explain the SxS part?

Comment: @jmac see currying: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: Jolly Good. Thank you.